# how to find physical page of user from kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

so I understand I can use get_user_pages to find the page of address but the probelm is that I dont know how to pass the size of the page to get_user_pages

```
void sys(char *user)
 {
  char *phyiscal=getphiscal(user);
  }
```

Comment: A *page* denotes a **minimal** memory unit which can be mapped on a given machine. You cannot change size of the page. E.g., if page size is `4k` and `user` points to the `5k`, then for access this address you should map the whole page `[4k;8k)`. It is impossible to map just range `[5k; 6k)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but how can I find the address of the pointer in the page?

Comment: You need to determine "unaligned" part of the address, and add this part to the physical address of the page. E.g. address 5k has "unaligned" part equal to 1k, because `(5k-1k) = 4k` which is divisible by 4k. So, if range [4k; 8k) would be mapped e.g. to [112k; 116k) then address 5k will be corresponded to `112k + 1k = 113k`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks so practically I need to add to my address the modulo of 4  of the size of the page?

Comment: Yes, but 4k is not a 4 but 4096.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks you so much again!!!